# error "The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data"

Tags: javascript, laravel

I create date of birth or date in register form? I am trying to make Register form. How can I do this? Script file not working

When i submitted form has error "The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data" Help me please

script files

```js
 <script>
        
    $('.date').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      locale: 'en',
      icons: {
        up: 'fas fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fas fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fas fa-chevron-right'
      }
    })

    $('.datetime').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
      locale: 'en',
      sideBySide: true,
      icons: {
        up: 'fas fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fas fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fas fa-chevron-right'
      }
    })

    $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'HH:mm:ss',
      icons: {
        up: 'fas fa-chevron-up',
        down: 'fas fa-chevron-down',
        previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
        next: 'fas fa-chevron-right'
      }
    })
    </script>
```

User models

```js
 public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat(config('project.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d') : null;
    }
```

blade file

```js
<div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">
       <i class="material-icons">event</i></span>
    </div>
      <input name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth" type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="{{ trans ('global.date_of_birth') }}..." value="{{ old('date_of_birth')  }}" required autocomplete="name">
  </div>
  @error('date_of_birth')
  <div class="error" for="date_of_birth">{{ $message }}</div>
  @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: what are you asking here actually??

Answer (score 1):

should using date time picker [enter link description here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-date-time-picker.html)

Answer (score 1):

The separation symbol could not be found Unexpected data found. Trailing data

[When I submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dwWd.png)